# jQuery sortable placeholder position (index)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to display the sortable element position (or index) in the sortable placeholder. It works when dragging the first element, not with others (position 0 instead of 1).

Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/Hw2rJ/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to a similar challenge and found this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-show-placeholders-position-and-give-it-a-number and with a little adaptation (and correction) got it work

```
$('.elements-sortable').sortable({
    placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
    opacity: 0.6,
    helper: 'clone',
    sort: function(event,ui){
        $(ui.placeholder).html(Number($('.elements-sortable > div:visible').index(ui.placeholder)+1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be coz it append new element before element you draging

so let's try this code

```
var position;
$(".elements-sortable").sortable({

placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
opacity: "0.6",

start: function(event, ui) {

    position = position = Number($(".elements-sortable > div:not(.ui-sortable-helper)").index(ui.placeholder)+1);
    $(".sortable-placeholder").html('Drop me at position ' + position);

},

change: function(event, ui) {
    position = position = Number($(".elements-sortable > div:not(.ui-sortable-helper)").index(ui.placeholder)+1);
    $(".sortable-placeholder").html('Drop me at position ' + position);
}
});
```

i've tested it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw2rJ/6/)

Comment: Yeah, I can do something like that for sure, but isn't there a "standard" way of getting that same index position on all elements?

Comment: i've fixed some code but i think sometimes it have a bug that i can't explain with when move div to the first position.

Answer (score -2):

try this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z315l/C8a2r/)

```
$(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function (e,ui ) {
        $("body").append("<p> current position : " + $(ui.item).prevAll().length + "</p>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope. That's not what was needed here.